# Syntax error near =~ operator

Tags: regex, bash, shell, operator-keyword, conditional-operator

When I run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "abcd" =~ ^.*$ ]]; then
    echo "something"
fi
```

I get:

```
./tmp2.sh: line 3: conditional binary operator expected
./tmp2.sh: line 3: syntax error near `=~'
./tmp2.sh: line 3: `if [[ "abcd" =~ ^.*$ ]]; then'
```

I've tried all suggestions I've found, but still the same:/
Help me, please!

Comment: [I've failed to reproduce this behaviour.](http://ideone.com/n22r76)

Comment: How are you running the script? Are you sure the script is being run by `bash`, not some other shell or `bash` in POSIX mode?

Comment: Which version of bash are you running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you're seeing a **bash-specific error message**, we can **rule out** that **something *other* than `bash`** is running the script (if it were a POSIX-features-only shell, such as `sh` on some systems, you'd instead see an error message relating to `[[`).

The most likely explanation:

- Your **`bash` version is `< 3.0`**, and therefore doesn't support the `=~` operator.

  - To verify, run `echo $BASH_VERSION` in your script.

The specific error you're seeing is bash's way of saying: "I'm seeing a string I don't recognize as an operator."

Comment: You got it right. I should have checked earlier versions too.

Comment: Sounds likely, but concerning how horribly outdated OP's system is. Bash 3 turns 10 in a couple weeks.

Answer (score 3):

Run your script with `bash script.sh` not `sh script.sh`. It probably would also work with `./script.sh` if `script.sh` is already executable since you're using the header `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
re='^.*$'
if [[ "abcd" =~ $re ]]; then
  echo "something"
fi
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain the syntax. Please expand on your answer.

Comment: This wouldn't help. The `=~` syntax works in all versions of Bash starting 3.0.

Comment: While storing your regex in an auxiliary variable does help in some situations (with regexes that contain `\ `-prefixed sequences such as `\<` or `\s`), this is NOT the problem here - yours an the OP's code are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost identical to the error you get in all versions of bash that support regex if you put `~=` rather than `=~`.

Comment: How is this answering the question?

Comment: Because I came here from google trying to investigate why I was getting "conditional binary operator expected" and it wasn't until I copied the example from here did I spot the obvious error. It looks almost identical to the error listed above and I have spent quite a while searching for this resolution. If you are on this page with that error and you haven't checked the =~ it is probably a far more common reason it's not working.

Comment: May be, but this doesn't answer actual question and shouldn't be here, SO is not a forum.

Comment: When you google "stack overflow" "syntax error near" "~=", this page is top of the list. It is not immediately obvious that google has swapped the =~ for you. This post answers that related question.